# anonymous android.view.View.onclicklistener error

Tags: android

I am trying to get the input of user from edit text, and then create more `Edittext` boxes into my `linear layout` depending on user input, but I am having this error on my code.

> EditText (android.content.Context)in EditText cannot be applied
>   to(anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener)

Here's some of my code.

```
linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
```

I have error on this line `final EditText ed = new EditText(this);`

```
    try{
        int noofstud = Integer.parseInt(numberofstudents.getText().toString()); //get number
        final EditText[] myEditText = new EditText[noofstud];

        for(int i = 0; i < noofstud; i++){
            final EditText ed = new EditText(this);
            linear.addView(ed);
            myEditText[i] = ed;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use your **ClassName.this** in new EditText(this);
suppose your class name is **MainActivity**
then use this as follows

```
final EditText ed = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
```